# How to determine the right time of Landsat 8?

Tags: landsat, time, date

Sorry, please help me clarify this issue.

Assume that I have information from a Landsat 8 image with the time shown as below:

Start time: 2018:288:03:13:25.1532590
Stop time: 2018:288:03:13:56.9232570

Does it mean the image was at 3:13m:25s UTC?

Answer (score 4):

The format of Landsat 8 start/stop times is: YYYY:DDD:HH:MM:SS. So in your example above, the start time would be Oct. 15, 2018 at 3:13:25.1532590 (3 hours, 13 minutes, 25.1532590 seconds).

You can refer to the Landsat documentation [here](https://landsat.usgs.gov/sites/default/files/documents/LSDS-809-Landsat8-Level1DFCB.pdf).